# Java arrays.binary search multiple matches?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I need to find all elements in sorted array with `Arrays.binarySearch` method. I want to iterate binary search in `lowerbound = pos + 1` (`pos` is previous match), but `binarySearch` is not guaranteed to return first match (min match index)?

How can I make this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily use the result of `binarySearch` to get all the matches :

```
long[] sortedArr = ...
int index = Arrays.binarySearch (sortedArr, value);
int first = index;
int last = index;
if (index >= 0) {
    while (first > 0 && sortedArr[first-1] == value)
        first--;
    while (last < sortedArr.length - 1 && sortedArr[last+1] == value)
        last++;
}
```

After you run this code, the indices between `first` and `last` (inclusive) are all the indices that contain the searched value.

Comment: I make it like you. Just I want know, maybe I can iterate this in 'one-line' style.

Comment: looping without braces won't pass code review around here.